# Git shows modified *.ipynb files, cannot reset, stash or switch branch

Tags: macos, bash, git, version-control

I've been having this reoccurring issue recently:

```
$ git status
On branch foo
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/foo'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   tools/notebook1.ipynb
        modified:   tools/notebook2.ipynb

$ git reset --hard
$ git status
On branch foo
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/foo'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   tools/notebook1.ipynb
        modified:   tools/notebook2.ipynb
$ git stash
$ git status
On branch foo
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/foo'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   tools/notebook1.ipynb
        modified:   tools/notebook2.ipynb
```

Nothing I do gets rid of the changed files, `git diff` shows no modification.

How can I a) figure out what non-content changes cause this and b) fix it without `git add`ing and committing them? Fwiw, I am using `pre-commit` in the repo, but that should not affect anything before `commit`.

Answer (score 1):

I found some configuration in `.git/config` that looked like this

```
[filter "nbstripout"]
    clean = \"venv/python3\" -m nbstripout
    smudge = cat
[diff "ipynb"]
    textconv = \"venv/python3\" -m nbstripout -t
```

Removing them solved this issue for now.